# How to change the orientation of gvisOrgChart in R?

Tags: r, googlevis, orgchart

I have built a giant org chart in R by using gvisOrgchart. My data has values and the parents.

When I run the following script:

```
Org1 <- plot(gvisOrgChart(data, idvar = "value", parentvar = "parent",
    tipvar="rand",  options=list(width=100,       height=100,allowCollapse=TRUE)))
```

I get a huge horizontal org chart. My question is below:

1. How can I change the orientation to horizontal?
2. Is there any other way except using googleVis in order to build org charts in R?
3. How to change distances between the boxes and the size of the text?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I also have same question. I would like to generate vertically, and wants the chart to be collapsed by default until I double click.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I still have no idea. You can try to rebuilt yours with JSON as here[example](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html)

Comment: I don't know Java Script, I know R and want to do this in R.

Comment: me too, I will post it here as soon as I find an answer